# ¿Sabrán como puedo Imprimir la siguiente lista en C#?

Tags: c#, lista, foreach

Tengo algún problema al intentar imprimir la lista creada, la lista la declaramos así:

```
  public List<Admin> baseAdmin = new List<Admin>()
```

El constructor de la clase admin lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
public Admin(string nombres, int numTrabajadores, string dependencias, string usuarios, string password, string email, long cel)
    {
        this.nombre = nombres;
        this.numTrabajador = numTrabajadores;
        this.dependencia = dependencias;
        this.usuario = usuarios;
        this.contraseña = password;
        this.correo = email;
        this.celular = cel;
    }
```

En esta lista creada guardamos los siguientes datos:

```
public void AltaAdmin()
   {
       baseAdmin.Add(new Admin( "Kareem", 318259478, "Estudiante", "user003", "pass7894", "kareem@gmail.com", 55874962));
       baseAdmin.Add(new Admin("Mariela", 318325961, "Estudiante", "user001", "pass1234", "mariela@gmail.com", 55861438));
       baseAdmin.Add(new Admin("Ivan", 318592776, "Estudiante", "user002", "pass4567", "ivan@gmail.com", 55620705));

   }
```

Para intentar imprimir los datos intentamos con cualquiera de las siguientes funciones, pero no funcionan :(

```
 public void imprimirAd(List<Admin> list)  
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("/" + list[i]);
        }
    }

 public void Imprimir(List<Admin> list)
    {
        foreach(var Panel in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Panel.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Esa lista queremos que se imprima al entrar en el case 4 de nuestro switch y la función la llamamos de la siguiente manera, al parecer si entra al case pero no imprime las listas ccon ninguna de las dos funciones

```
  case 4: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Lista de Administradores");
                   Imprimir(baseAdmin);
                    imprimirAd(baseAdmin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Itachi tu problema es que estas imprimiendo literalmente la instancia de la clase  Admin lo cual te imprime la posicion en memoria RAM de ese objeto, si lo que quieres es imprimir los datos de los admins debes de acceder a los datos de los objetos

```
 public void imprimirAd(List<Admin> list)  
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("/" + list[i].nombre);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + list[i].numTrabajadores);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + list[i].dependencias);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + list[i].dependencias);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + list[i].password);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + list[i].email);
    }
 }
```

El otro metodo quedaria de esta manera

```
public void Imprimir(List<Admin> list)
{
    foreach(Admin Panel in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("/" + Panel.nombre);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + Panel.numTrabajadores);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + Panel.dependencias);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + Panel.dependencias);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + Panel.password);
        Console.WriteLine("/" + Panel.email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Luis, probé las funciones y no maraca ningún error y al ejecutarlas no muestra nada, pasaba algo similar con las anteriores funciones, entran al case pero no pasa nada.